# I want to Share my raw audio.mp3 file through intent but I an getting error

Tags: java

Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.audio);

```
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("audio/*");
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Code instead of Above.**

```
InputStream inputStream;
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
                try {
                    inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.audio);
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                            new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "audio.mp3"));

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    inputStream.close();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audio.mp3"));
                intent.setType("audio/*");
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share sound"));
```

Comment: Just so you know, you can edit your Question. As this is not an enswer, I suggest you remove it and add the code to your question